# Not understanding the sentences with the formula 'word + out '

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, definition

Exist a pattern that I already do not know to decipher each phrase with the formula word + out?

Work Out = Excercise

Deck Out = Decorate

Force out = Compel to leave

How does adding out is related to the definition?

How do native people have the skill to know the nuanced meanings of the myriad of phrases with the formula word + out, and how I can have that skill? Or they memorize them all?

Comment: _Deck out_ means _decorate_, not _decorated_. _Force out_ means to compel someone to leave a job or place. This is just vocabulary that you have to learn in the same way that you learn new words in a foreign language.

Comment: Yes, mostly you just need to treat "Work out" and Deck out" as though they were single words that you have to learn. There _is_ a pattern, but it is very limited: "_verb_ out" sometimes has a sense of completion; but not always, and there is often a special meaning  that you couldn't guess. So in your examples, _work out_ = "calculate, find the answer" has a sense of completion, but "work" on its own doesn't mean calculate; while your _work out_ = "exercise" is completely unpredictable. _Deck out_ again has a sense of completion, but "deck"  is rare. "Force out" doesn't mean "compel".

Comment: @ColinFine for example [**bring out**](https://i.imgur.com/YBToN8D.png) is a word of completion right?  Hence means bring something completely right?

Comment: @PabloRamosEscalona: No. In all the senses of _bring out_ that I can think of, _out_ has a more or less literal meaning. In _bring out_ = "release (a product), publish", the "out" means "out into the world"; in _bring out_ = "accentuate (a flavour, a quality of something, a theme in prose)" the "out" means "out of the creation".

Comment: @ColinFine "and there is often a special meaning that you couldn't guess" why not? I'm "doomed" to not being native? So what is the takeaway? Do I need to memorize them as single words? You as a native speaker do not decipher this phenomenon, really? Or you memorize the myriad of combinations word + out?

Comment: @PabloRamosEscalona: I don't know for sure, but I think the answer to all your questions is "yes". As a native speaker, I sometimes encounter phrasal verbs that are new to me, just as I sometimes encounter words that are new to me: the meaning may be obvious in context, or it may be baffling, or mislead me.